# How do I properly use window results on consecutive windows?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

## A bit of background

I am using a Stream Execution Environment and I am successfully processing a stream of data coming from a kafka server with Session Windows. After x amount of windows are processed I want to collect all of them and make an additional calculation. This is where the issue occurs. I can not figure out how to process them all together properly.

## What I tried

I have tried adding another window after the first `result` of window streams but I can not use `keyBy` to perform a grouped reduce method since it is used on a `WindowAll` window. I also tried using `Window` since `keyBy` is supported by it, but then the session window (the one with the 25 secs time gap, code included below) creates the windows more frequently than it should. The only way it works is when I tried adding `.process` or `.apply` after the window function and then it allows me to use `keyBy` and the processing is happening when I want to: after all the initial windowed operations are gathered. Even then something is not right because I am having duplicate instances of object in the stream as it's showing me progressive results. Which means that if I were to export it, it would also display those incomplete results. This is a somewhat functional workaround but from what I've read on the official documentation `.process` is not very optimal in terms of time complexity. If an alternative could be used I would love to know.

## The code

The application starts by reading a kafka stream. A thing to note here is that the session windows with the 5 sec gap are used because I pass the files that I read into kafka with a 5 seconds delay. Each file being read represents a day and the first windowed operation aims to gather the users from all the days into a single user object. The second windowed operation aims to gather the users from all the single days and reduce them as well.

```
KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
            .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
            .setTopics("quickstart-events")
            .setGroupId("test-consumer-group")
            .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
            .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
            .build();
```

After that I take the `source` stream and parse the string data into class objects with the Star() flapMap function. Then I reduce all objects of the same user into one (keeping some metrics)

```
   result =  graphData.rebalance().flatMap(new Star()).keyBy(value -> value.getUser()).reduce(...)
                .window(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(5)))
```

`result` contains the stream of all the windows I want to gather and process together.

```
 result.windowAll(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(25))).process(new ProcessAllWindowFunction<AdjacencyList, AdjacencyList, TimeWindow>() {
            @Override
            public void process(Context context, Iterable<AdjacencyList> iterable, Collector<AdjacencyList> collector) throws Exception {

              for (AdjacencyList it: iterable) {
                
                    collector.collect(it);
                    
              }
            }
        }).keyBy(value -> value.getUser()).reduce(...).filter(...).flatMap(...);
```

Is there something crucial I am missing? Thanks in advance to everyone who reads this.

Comment: Not sure I've correctly understood the details. If you will share more of the code that will hopefully clarify exactly what you've done.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have added a bit more details and code snippets, hopefully now it is clearer.